# Why do I have a dracut initramfs in /var/tmp?

Tags: filesystems, sles, initramfs, dracut

I never used dracut so far. I understood dracut filesystems ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk)) as temporary systems that help mounting system specific kernel modules during the boot process. But after successful boot of my SLES 12 Server VM I still have a dracut file system under `/var/tmp/dracut.2jqPCx`.

Do I still need it? Where do I find information about how to get rid of this extra file system? Or, if it is essential, were do I find information about the reasoning for keeping it after the boot process?

Answer (score 2):

SUSE uses dracut to create initramfs, which is an initial image used by the kernel for loading modules needed on boot, for example RAID or iSCSI.

The initramfs image generated by dracut is stored on `/boot/initramfs-<kernel version>.img`. Anyway seems that your server created a temporary file on `/var/tmp` during an initramfs generation process.

[On dracut man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/dracut.8.html) you can find information about a temporary directory used for that process:

> ```
>   --tmpdir <temporary directory>
>       specify temporary directory to use.
>
>       Default: /var/tmp
> ```

Initramfs is generated every time you update kernel. It's possible that a generation didn't exit cleanly and lets the temporary file.

Do you still need it? For sure not because your boot process uses kernel and initramfs (`/boot/initramfs-<kernel version>.img`) only. But it won't hurts if you let it alone.